# Converting String to Date with SQL in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

a similar question has been asked, but the examples use different formats so I haven't been able to solve my problem. For some reason, the database my company uses stores dates as the following:

```
1131112
1130919
```

The first is November 12, 2013; the second is September 19, 2013. Not sure why there is a 1 at the beginning. I am trying to convert it to mm/dd/yy so I can use VBA to just grab invoices that are within a user specified date.

The code I am using is the following which results in a database error '1004':

```
SELECT date(translate('xyymmdd',INDATE,'mmddyy')) FROM INVOICED WHERE (INMFGR || INCOLO || INPATT = 'MMMTEST')
```

Comment: Does db2 not have anything resembling substring functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your DB2 version and platform (which you strangely did not indicate), you might be able to do something like

```
select to_date(substr(INDATE,2),'yymmdd') from INVOICED
```

PS. Your use of `translate()` seems wrong. You can look up its proper usage in the manual for the appropriate DB2 version.

Comment: I'm not the DBA, so don't have direct access to that info or currently know how to get it. I'm just some office guy with the dB as a data source who knows a little SQL and VBA.

Read the online manual for DB2 and got the correct syntax. I don't think translate() is what I am after. It just replaces exact matches in the same place holder with what you want it to be, which doesn't work for me. (That is probably a bad way of explaining it). I need it to take the 2nd position in the original string and move it over 'here', for example. I'll try to figure out to_date.

Comment: Ok, go it figured out using the SUBSTR. Thanks!